# How to remove hidden character in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, worksheet-function

I have an excel table like the following, I want to delete the blank cell by:

**Find & select -> go to special-> blanks**
then ok, but "no cells where found" appears,

[image]
after I tried pressing the delete button on an empty cell and repeating the steps above, an empty cell was detected.

How do I delete all the invisible characters?

Comment: Use Code formula and select any cell that appears blank. This will provide you what character is stored in that particular cell.

Comment: Oh yes, I have result #VALUE

Comment: Try to find if there is space in the range.

Answer (score 0):

In the Column to the right of your data enter =len(A1) and fill down. The space character will have a length of 1.Filter the ones by that Column. Select all the Rows marked as 1 and click Ctrl+ - (minus sign) on the numerical keypad and then remove filter.